# Sybase ASEBulkCopy is not working

Tags: sap-ase

Sybase ASEBulkCopy is not working. 
I have set the EnableBulkLoad attribute to 1 in the connection string. 
It is uploading 1 record at a time even after setting the batch size to 500. The other settings EnableBulkLoad attribute is set to 1 in the connection string.

What other settings am I missing. 
Please someone help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Whether bulk load actually happens depends on other things as well, such as the presence of indexes on the target table. By enabling bulk load you're basically telling the ASE server that it should try to do bulk uploading if it can -- but maybe it cannot so it uses non-bulk.

I'm not sure I understand the details of your question though. What do you mean by "upload"? Does your client app send only 1 record to the ASE server at a time? 
Or does it mean that ASE performs regular inserts instead of bulk inserts? If the latter, how did you diagnose that?

I recommend trying it first with the 'bcp' client utility to figure out if bulk loading is possible to start with.

Comment: Hi Rob, I tried the BCP commons line until and both export and import of data works fine and just a couple of seconds. The problem is from the application. I'm trying to bulk load with batch size set to 500, but the copy activity is taking long time. I know this fact because, during the copy process, the  I'm running the select count statement in the table. And i see  the count incrementing very slowly

Comment: That suggests that the way your application uses the bulk API, is not optimal. I can't say much more intelligent about it though....